# PixiJS Parallax Scrolling Background and Static Sprites

Tags: javascript, html, sprite, parallax, pixi.js

I'm working on a parallax sidescroller game in PixiJS for a school project, and I'm running into a bit of bother with getting things to work properly. Essentially, I have three backgrounds (using a class that extends from PIXI.extras.TilingSprite) that scroll at different speeds and a player (moving in a completely different way) when the user presses either of the arrow keys. I'm also using the Pixi Viewport extension (https://github.com/davidfig/viewport), to get a nice and clean view of the game following the player. It looks great and all (despite some issues I need to fix with shaders and what not), but now I'm trying to add static sprites into the game, and that unfortunately does not work as I thought it would. Here's a GIF of how it looks in-game:

### [Example GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytNXd.gif)

Please excuse the awful quality,  I had to jump through a few hoops to record that footage and make it into a GIF format.

Here's the relevant classes that I've made thus far :

```
class Monster extends PIXI.Sprite
{
    constructor(texture, x, y)
    {
        super(texture);
        this.anchor.x = 0.5;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class ParallaxLayer extends PIXI.extras.TilingSprite{
    constructor(texture, deltaX = 0.5){
        super(PIXI.loader.resources[texture].texture, viewport.worldWidth, viewport.worldHeight);
        this.vx = 0;
        this.viewportX = 0;
        this.deltaX = deltaX;
        this.filters = [];
        this.setViewportX(-680);
        this.x = -680;
    }
    setViewportX(newViewportX){
        if (newViewportX > 0)
        {
            let distanceTravelled = newViewportX - this.viewportX;
            this.viewportX = newViewportX;
            this.tilePosition.x -= (distanceTravelled * this.deltaX);
        }

    }
    getViewportX(){
        return this.viewportX;
    }
}
```

And here's the code that's running in my game loop to move the parallax backgrounds and the player:

```
   // changes 'x' tile position (parallax scrolling effect
    for (var i = 0; i < bgTilingSprites.length; i++) 
    {
        if (bgTilingSprites[i].vx != 0)
        {
            let scale = bgTilingSprites[i].tileScale.x;
            let speed = deltaTime * scale * bgTilingSprites[i].vx;
            bgTilingSprites[i].setViewportX(bgTilingSprites[i].viewportX + ((i+1) * speed));
            //bgTilingSprites[i].tilePosition.x -= (i + 1) * speed;


            // it's "fix" a tilisprite position bug
            var width = bgTilingSprites[i].texture.width * scale; 
            if (bgTilingSprites[i].tilePosition.x >= width) 
            {
                //bgTilingSprites[i].tilePosition.x -= width;
                bgTilingSprites[i].setViewportX(width);
            }
            else if (bgTilingSprites[i].tilePosition.x <= -width) 
            {
                //bgTilingSprites[i].tilePosition.x += width;
                bgTilingSprites[i].setViewportX(-width);
            }
        }
    }
    // If the player's x velocity is not 0
    if (player.vx != 0)
    {
        // Calculate player speed
        let playerSpeed = deltaTime * player.vx;
        // Increment player's position by their speed
        if (player.x > -675)
        {
            player.x += playerSpeed;
            // Animate the player
            if (player.playing != true)
            {
                player.texture = playerWalkFrames[0];
                player.play();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (player.playing != false){
            player.gotoAndStop(0);
            player.texture = playerTexture;
            player.footstepToPlay = 0;
            player.footstepDelay = 0;
        }

    }
```

If there is any other information that would be beneficial to helping me solve this conundrum, I would be happy to provide. I'm still very new to Stack Overflow (and I'm nowhere near an expert on JavaScript), so I would greatly appreciate advice that would help me get the best help possible for this.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want it to look?

Right now I see the background layers are moving past the monster, so it looks like the monster is actually moving to the right, correct?

Well, all the parallax backgrounds are actually moving to the left, so the whole "world" is moving to the left. 
Now, the monster is not moving at all (just the viewport extension camera is moving, that’s why the monster moves on the screen)
But since everything is moving to the left, makes sense that a static sprite will seem to be moving to the right.

You move the backgrounds relative to the players movement.
perhaps you should do the same to the monster, make it move like the backgrounds at a speed somewhere between the 1st and 2nd layer.